# Flutter Firebase StreamBuilder List<Future<Item>> isn't <List<Item>> error

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, stream-builder

Hello I am quite experienced with Futures but Streams are new to me. I am having this error in my Stream builder function where I can't get the return type to be not a future

Code with error:

```
Stream<List<MessageModel>> getMessages() {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snap = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('messages')
        .doc(groupChatId)
        .snapshots();
    return snap.map((event) => event.docs.map((doc) => return MessageModel.getMessagedata(doc)).toList());
  }
```

other related functions:

```
class MessageModel {
    static Future<MessageModel> getMessagedata(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc) async {
        Userdata postUser = await DatabaseService.getPostUserDataFromFirestore(doc['userId']);
        return MessageModel.fromDoc(doc, postUser);
      }

factory  MessageModel.fromDoc(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc, Userdata authordata) {
    return MessageModel(
        doc['content'],
        doc['timestamp'],
        doc['authorId'],
        doc['type'],
        authordata
    );
  }
}
```

error message:

```
The return type 'List<Future<MessageModel>>' isn't a 'List<MessageModel>', as required by the closure's context.
```

I also tried this code but got the same error:

```
return snap.map((event) => event.docs.map((doc) async => await return MessageModel.getMessagedata(doc)).toList());
```

Comment: you need to use `Future.wait` in order to wait for all `MessageModel`s and then use `Stream.asyncMap` on the result

Comment: and the easiest way to do that is just to add `.asyncMap(Future.wait)` at the end of `return snap.map(...);` - notice that you dont need `.toList()` in that case